# Error estimate for sequence defining e

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is there an estimate for error of $e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ ?thanks

Answer (score 5):

The power series for $\log(1+x)$ yields
$$
n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
$$
applying $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ and the power series for $e^x$ gives
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\frac{e}{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
$$

Comment: Awesome. Thnaks!